# In Eclipse, how to copy an existing project to another project?

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse, I have one existing project, A.  Right now, I have just created another project, B, which is empty. Is it possible to copy all the files of project A, including its source code and related libraries to project B? There are a lot of involved libraries in project A. How to do this copying process correctly to ensure the copied files can still be compiled?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can Import the project

OR

Assuming both project A and B are of same type:

You can copy the contents of `src` folder as it is.

For the libraries, just go to the build path and add them in the ssame way you did for project A.

Comment: How about the scenario that, project A was created as normal project,a nd project B was created as dynamic web project?

Comment: My answer will hold true in this case. Because, even in that case you can copy your java source files to the src folder and libraries must be added as well. But who will do such a thing? Did my solution work, btw?

Comment: I manually copy the source file, abc.java from /user/workspace1/project1/src to user/workspace2/project2/src. But after I open the project 2 under eclipse, I could not find abc.java under src directory. What did I do wrong?

Comment: first of all make sure that you are copying in the right folder. then refresh the project. worst-of-the-worst-case, restart eclipse.

Comment: Yes, refreshing works. Right now, I am trying to configure path for the new project. After clicking the Libraries tab (build path window) for the old project, i can find a lot of libries. How can I add these many libraries for the new project? Thanks.

Comment: Just click 'Add External JARs' and specify the path of the JARs you want to add. And if it working for you, how about accepting the answer? It will be helpful for future visitors as well.

Comment: Bhushan, thanks for the answer. My current question is that how to handle the scneario where there are a lot of involved libraries. I have posted this new question in another post.

Comment: You can't simply import a copy of a project as is. You'll be greeted with the following error message: *Some projects cannot be imported because they already exist in the workspace*.

Answer (score 50):

This question appears in Google search as top result for query "copy project in eclipse".

To copy project in Eclipse:

1) right click on project in Package Explorer view;

2) choose Copy;

3) right click on free place in Package Explorer view;

4) choose Paste;

5) enter new name in the prompt window.

To answer actual question, the best way is to delete project B and after --  copy project A as explained above and give it name B.

Comment: This answer best suits the title of the question.

Comment: This is the best answer!

Comment: This used to work for me, I get the prompt window. It even suggests a name for the copied project. When pressing ok, the new copied project is nowhere to be seen. Tried the ctrl +c then ctrl +v approach as well. :-(

Comment: I found this solution works, BUT... the source project has to be open.

Answer (score 16):

1. Close Eclipse
2. **Copy** the folder of **existing project** to anywhere on your disk.
3. Start Eclipse. Turn off the automatically build.
4. In the Eclipse do Refactor / **Rename** to the **new project name**. (If it connected to CVS/SVN disconnect before rename.)
5. **Import** back the **old project** from place where you copied in the second step.
6. Turn on the automatically build.

Enjoy them!

Comment: With this method will be copied all contents of project: all settings, classpath, etc, not only source codes (like in Bhushan's answer)

Comment: What's with all the exclamation marks? I read that list as if you were yelling at me.

Answer (score 6):

Since B is empty, you can just copy project A in the Package Explorer and name the copy B.

Comment: I do it exactly this way. If necessary I rename source files manually, but all settings including libraries are inherited this way.

Answer (score 5):

1. Create a duplicate/copy of an existing project (in the workspace).
2. Then in Eclipse, click file->import
3. Select import existing projects into workspace
4. Check the radio button "Select root directory"
5. Browse your project (the new file you copied in workspace in step 1)
6. Done!

Comment: thank you. It worked like a charm as compared to the other solutions...it's also easy to do this

Answer (score 1):

In the project Explorer, right click your old project, click **"Copy"**, right click again click on **"Paste"** this time, change the default given name **"Copy of My_Old_Project"** to any of your choice, after the copy is done, go to the **"Search"** tab in Eclipse, then to --> **"Search"**, on the File Search, type the old name of your project, make sure that your scope is only **"Enclosing project"**, change all **occurrences** into the new name, run the project, you are all set...

only thing I noticed about this is that the url will still be of the old project.

Answer (score 0):

For a Gradle project, I had to add two extra steps to mOna's answer, which I will copy for completeness.

1. Create a duplicate/copy of an existing project (in the workspace).
2. Then in Eclipse, click file->import
3. Select import existing projects into workspace
4. Check the radio button "Select root directory"
5. Browse your project (the new file you copied in workspace in step 1)
6. Edit .project file and change the  and the  to match the new project.
7. Edit settings.gradle and change rootProject.name to match the new project.

I assume that the renaming in some of the above answers does step 6, but I couldn't get it to work.  No matter what I tried, without those extra steps the code looked ok but dependencies were not handled correctly and errors appeared everywhere.  I was even able to run gradle on my project from the command line and it "built", but was actually building the old project.

Answer (score -1):

Eclipse has a option in file menu like import existing projec.From that you can import the existing project with all content.I hope this is the solution that you are looking for.